# setting default width for collection_select in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I need to set a default width for a collection_select in Rails. I tried this but it is not work:

```
<%= u.collection_select :program_id, Program.where(:status => true), :id, :name , :include_blank=> true, :class=>'foo'%>
```

also I tried:

```
<%= u.collection_select :program_id, Program.where(:status => true), :id, :name , :include_blank=> true, {:class=>'foo'}%>

<%= u.collection_select :program_id, Program.where(:status => true), :id, :name , :include_blank=> true, :style=>'width:50%'%>
```

and they didn't work, any ideas??

Comment: What did your `'foo'` class look like in the CSS file?

Comment: @ScottJShea the class may look like that: `.foo{
  width: 23px;
}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I figure it out:

```
<%= u.collection_select :program_id, Program.where(:status => true), :id, :name , {:include_blank=> true}, {:class=>'foo'}%>
```

It works now!